# Use of .C in shiny

Tags: c, r, shiny

I am trying to use the function `Qn` from the robustbase library in shiny. This function makes a call to the C routine Qn0 as as follows:

```
.C(Qn0, as.double(x), n, res = double(1))$res
```

When I run (say) `Qn(rnorm(10))` inside R it runs perfectly fine but when I run it inside shiny it gives the error message

> Error in Qn(rnorm(10)) : object 'Qn0' not found

Here is some sample code

ui.R

```
 shinyUI(fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
       sidebarPanel(),
       mainPanel(uiOutput("txt"))
   )    
 ))
```

server.R

```
 library(robustbase)
 shinyServer(function(input, output) {        
      output$txt <- renderText({
          print(getDLLRegisteredRoutines("robustbase"))         
          Qn(rnorm(10))
      })
 })
```

the getDLLRegisteredRoutines("robustbase") lists the Qn0, but then I get the error anyway. I suspect there is an issue with the namespace, but I haven't been able to figure out what it is.

Wolfgang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the problem by installing the latest version of R and shiny. Thanks to tchakravarty for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
library(robustbase)

ui_foo = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(uiOutput("txt"))
  )    
))

server_foo =  shinyServer(function(input, output) {        
  output$txt <- renderText({
    print(getDLLRegisteredRoutines("robustbase"))         
    Qn(rnorm(10))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui_foo, server = server_foo)
```

does not throw any errors for me. Here is my `sessionInfo`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] robustbase_0.92-5    RSQLite_1.0.0        shiny_0.13.2         stringr_1.0.0        zoo_1.7-12          
 [6] chron_2.3-47         ggplot2_2.1.0        RMySQL_0.10.9        DBI_0.4-1            assertthat_0.1      
[11] readr_0.2.2          dplyr_0.4.3          XLConnect_0.2-11     XLConnectJars_0.2-9  readxl_0.1.1        
[16] openxlsx_3.0.0       lubridate_1.5.6.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.4      DEoptimR_1.0-4   plyr_1.8.3.9000  tools_3.2.5      digest_0.6.9     jsonlite_0.9.19 
 [7] gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-33  parallel_3.2.5   rJava_0.9-8      grid_3.2.5       data.table_1.9.6
[13] R6_2.1.2         magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.0     htmltools_0.3.5  mime_0.4         colorspace_1.2-6
[19] xtable_1.8-2     httpuv_1.3.3     labeling_0.3     stringi_1.0-1    lazyeval_0.1.10  munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: Strange! I ran the app exactly as you did and I get the same error! The only differences I see from your sessionInfo are: I run Win7, R-3.2.2 and shiny_0.12.2, but none of this should matter.

Comment: @WolfgangRolke Why don't you deploy this code to shinyapps.io and see if it raises an error  there.